# How to read ASTER metadata in IDL?

Tags: r, batch, idl

I'm trying to read many ASTER images (1B mainly) in IDL (I can try in R also). I'm used to work with Landsat, but the aster metadata is complicated. I write a code with a lots of conditional that can read the image parameters (angles, dates, etc). But I want to know if there is other way I can read this.

Besides, I want to know if all the aster metadata have the same format, so I can batch all the images with the same code (or I need to modify it image by image).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two ways to read aster metadata in envi (hdf format).

1.- using "envi_file_query" to read a particular attribute

```
; set the name of the file
FILE_NAME='link to .hdf'
; open data as aster image
    envi_open_data_file, FILE_NAME, /aster, r_fid=fid

;query the metadata inserted in the hdf (global attributes)
envi_file_query, fid[0], nb=nb, ACQUISITION_TIME=ACQUISITION_TIME, BBL=BBL, BNAMES=BNAMES, BYTE_SWAP=BYTE_SWAP, CLASS_NAMES=CLASS_NAMES, CLOUD_COVER=CLOUD_COVER, DATA_GAINS=DATA_GAINS, DATA_OFFSETS=DATA_OFFSETS, DATA_TYPE=DATA_TYPE, DEF_STRETCH=DEF_STRETCH, DESCRIP=DESCRIP, DIMS=DIMS, FILE_TYPE=FILE_TYPE,FNAME=FNAME, FWHM=FWHM, INTERLEAVE=INTERLEAVE, NB=NB, NL=NL, NS=NS, OFFSET=OFFSET, REFLECTANCE_SCALE_FACTOR=REFLECTANCE_SCALE_FACTOR, SENSOR_TYPE =SENSOR_TYPE , SOLAR_IRRADIANCE=SOLAR_IRRADIANCE, SNAME=SNAME, SUN_AZIMUTH=SUN_AZIMUTH, SUN_ELEVATION=SUN_ELEVATION, WAVELENGTH_UNITS=WAVELENGTH_UNITS, WL=WL
```

more information: http://www.exelisvis.com/docs/ENVI_FILE_QUERY.html

2.- using "metadata" to read all the metadata

```
; set the name of the file
FILE_NAME='link to .hdf'
;open data as aster image
    raster = e.OpenRaster(FILE_NAME, EXTERNAL_TYPE="eos_aster")

;read metadata by subsystem (VNIR, 3B, SWIR, TIR)
metadata0 = raster[0].METADATA
```

more information: http://www.exelisvis.com/docs/ENVIRasterMetaData.html